# Memcpy segmentation fault even when memory is allocated

Tags: c++, file, mmap, memcpy

I'm attempting to copy the data from one file by writing it to memory and then copy it into another using memcpy but I'm stumped. I cannot get it to stop giving me segmentation fault. I have a feeling it has something to do with the allocated memory, but I also made sure the file size of the output file is the same as the first one so it wouldn't have that problem and can paste the data into it.

*edit: I've come to figure it has to do with char* out_data and how I'm attempting to copy data into it when it is read only. Not sure how to go about this.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;



#define OUTPUT_MODE 0700         // protection bits for output file

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    /* Open the specified file */
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);



    // stats.st_size is a variable containing the size of inFile.txt
    struct stat instats;
    if (stat(argv[1], &instats)==0)
            cout<<endl<<"inFile size "<<instats.st_size;
    else
           cout<<"Unable to get file properties.\n";



    /* Get the page size  */
    int pagesize = getpagesize();
    cout<<endl<<"page size is " <<pagesize<<"\n";

    /******************Creation of outFile.txt******************/
    int out_fd = creat(argv[2], OUTPUT_MODE);


    char* in_data = (char*)mmap(NULL, instats.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    ftruncate(out_fd, instats.st_size);


    char* out_data = (char*)mmap(NULL, instats.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, out_fd, 0);


// THIS LINE IS THE CULPRIT 
    memcpy(out_data, in_data, instats.st_size);


    /* Unmap the shared memory region */
    munmap(in_data, instats.st_size);
    munmap(out_data, instats.st_size);

    /* Close the file */
    close(fd);
    close(out_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check that all the system calls succeeded, especially the `mmap`.

Comment: You are not doing any error handling to make sure that `open()`, `creat()`, and `mmap()` are actually successful before calling `memcpy()`

Comment: You have an `outstats` that is never defined, is it supposed to be `instats`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've done some testing to make sure they are, and the file does get created with creat, I know it does open cause I outputted the data from the indata with cout and it showed it. My problem is that I'm attempting to do memcpy on a char* (out_data) and since that makes it read only, that doesn't work.

Comment: @NateEldredge Fixed that, sorry

Comment: @Zlorpo123 you are not creating read-only maps, so that is not the problem. But did you make sure `mmap()` is not returning NULL?

Comment: Also, I cut off alot of the testing code that checked if open, creat, and mmap were successful to make it easier to read the code.

Comment: You are running `memcpy` on a pointer you haven't allocated any space to.

Comment: I'll bet you twenty bucks the `mmap` of `out_fd` failed.  And I know why...

Comment: @AlexReynolds Which pointer? For out_data I thought I did? Could you run me through that.

Comment: @NateEldredge I just ran this under it: 
if(!out_data)
 {
  cout<<"\n"<<"mapping did not succeed"<<"\n";
  exit(1);
 }

And it finished to the end. Care to say why it failed?

Comment: If you hadn't stripped out the error checking before posting, someone could have spotted that the error checking was wrong...

Comment: Why are you using `mmap` and not standard `ifstream` and `ofstream`? They are about the same performance-wise.

Comment: Its for purposes of using these libraries and practicing with them. Trust me I would've used those anyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`creat` creates a file which is only open for writing.  You cannot `mmap` such a file descriptor because there is no such thing as write-only memory.  If you were to check the return value from the `mmap` of `out_fd`, you would find that it failed, with `errno == EACCES`.  When `mmap` fails it returns an invalid pointer `MAP_FAILED` (not NULL but typically `-1`) which causes a segfault when `memcpy` attempts to write there.

Note that `if (!out_data)` is therefore the wrong test for failure of `mmap`; you must use `if (out_data == MAP_FAILED)`.

Instead of `creat`, use `open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, OUTPUT_MODE)`.

Comment: Yep, youre right. I was told I need to use creat though like: out_fd = creat(argv[2], OUTPUT_MODE);

Comment: Well, whoever told you that is wrong, I'm afraid.  If you do that then you will not be able to use `mmap` to access the file, though you could still use `write()` instead.

Comment: Got it, I'll talk to them.